# Avoiding circular dependencies the right way - NestJS

Tags: typescript, design-patterns, dependency-injection, graphql, nestjs

Say I have a `StudentService` with a method that adds lessons to a student and a `LessonService` with a method that adds students to a lesson. In both my Lesson and Student Resolvers I want to be able to update this lesson <---> student relationship. So in my `LessonResolver` I have something along the lines of:

```
  async assignStudentsToLesson(
    @Args('assignStudentsToLessonInput')
    assignStudentsToLesson: AssignStudentsToLessonInput,
  ) {
    const { lessonId, studentIds } = assignStudentsToLesson;
    await this.studentService.assignLessonToStudents(lessonId, studentIds); **** A.1 ****
    return this.lessonService.assignStudentsToLesson(lessonId, studentIds); **** A.2 ****
  }
```

and essentially the reverse in my `StudentResolver`

The difference between **A.1** and **A.2** above is that the `StudentService` has access to the `StudentRepository` and the `LessonService` has access to the `LessonRepository` - which I believe adheres to a solid separation of concerns.

However, it seems to be an anti-pattern that the `StudentModule` must import the `LessonModule` and the `LessonModule` must import the `StudentModule`. This is fixable using the `forwardRef` method, but in the [NestJS Documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency) it mentions this pattern should be avoided if possible:

> While circular dependencies should be avoided where possible, you
>   can't always do so. *(is this one of those cases?)*

This seems like it should be a common issue when using DI, but I'm struggling to get a definitive answer as to what options are available that can eliminate this situation, or if I've stumbled upon a situation where it's unavoidable.

The ultimate goal is for me to be able to write the two GraphQL queries below:

```
query {
  students {
    firstName
    lessons {
      name
    }
  }
}

query {
  lessons {
    name
    students {
      firstName
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to drop the dependencies altogether and instead introduce a third module that depends on the other two.
In your case, you could merge your two resolvers into a single `StudentLessonResolver` that lives in its own module, say `ResolverModule`:

```
async assign({ lessonId, studentIds }: AssignStudentsToLessonInput) {
  await this.studentService.assignLessonToStudents(lessonId, studentIds);
  return this.lessonService.assignStudentsToLesson(lessonId, studentIds);
}
```

So `StudentModule` and `LessonModule` are now completely independent, while `ResolverModule` depends on both of them. No cycle anymore :)

If for some reason you need to have two resolvers and have them update each other, you could use events or callbacks to publish changes.
You would then again introduce a third module which listens to those events and updates the other module.

```
type AssignCallback = (assignStudentsToLesson: AssignStudentsToLessonInput) => Promise<void>;

class LessonResolver {  // and similar for StudentResolver
  private assignCallbacks: AssignCallback[] = [];

  // ... dependencies, constructor etc.

  onAssign(callback: AssignCallback) {
    assignCallbacks.push(callback);
  }

  async assignStudentsToLesson(
    @Args('assignStudentsToLessonInput')
    assignStudentsToLesson: AssignStudentsToLessonInput,
  ) {
    const { lessonId, studentIds } = assignStudentsToLesson;
    await this.lessonService.assignStudentsToLesson(lessonId, studentIds); **** A.2 ****
    for (const cb of assignCallbacks) {
      await cb(assignStudentsToLesson);
    }
  }
}

// In another module
this.lessonResolver.onAssign(({ lessonId, studentIds }) => {
  this.studentService.assignLessonToStudents(lessonId, studentIds);
});
this.studentResolver.onAssign(({ lessonId, studentIds }) => {
  this.lessonService.assignStudentsToLesson(lessonId, studentIds);
});
```

Again, you break the cycle because `StudentModule` and `LessonModule` do not know about each other, while your registered callbacks guarantee that calling either resolver results in both services being updated.

If you are using a reactive library such as RxJS, instead of managing callbacks manually you should use a `Subject<AssignStudentsToLessonInput>` to which Resolvers publish and the newly introduced module subscribes.

**Update**

As the OP suggested, there are other alternatives as well, such as injecting both repositories into both services. But if each module contains both the repository and the service, i.e. if you import `LessonRepository` and `LessonService` from `LessonModule`, this would not work, since you would still have the cyclic dependency on the module level.
But if there really is a tight connection between students and lessons, you could also merge the two module into a single one, and there would be no problem.

A similar option would be to change the single resolver of the first solution to a service that uses the repositories directly. Whether this is a good option depends on the complexity of managing the stores. In the long run, you are probably better off going through the service.

One advantage I see in the single resolver/service solution is that it offers a single solution for assigning students to a lesson, whereas in the event solution, studentService.assignLessonToStudents and lessonService.assignStudentsToLesson effectively do exactly the same thing, so it is not clear which one should be used.

Comment: interesting approach! I had thought of using a third resolver but wasn't sure if that was me over-engineering and failing to see a simpler solution. One idea I just thought of was to alternatively inject the `StudentRepository` and `LessonRepository` into both the `StudentService` and `LessonService`. This way each service has both repos and can update them accordingly. My only gripe about this method is it seems to introduce duplicate business logic. Curious what your thoughts are?

Comment: I just tried your first approach and it works great. I appreciate your feedback!

Comment: Thanks! I also updated the answer to consider your proposal.

Comment: What if I use async events everywhere instead of using forwardRef, resolver module, etc.? @mperktold

Comment: That's illustrated by the second code example, isn't it?