# NestJs circular dependency issue

Tags: nestjs, circular-dependency

i have a question about resolving the circular dependency between a couple of nestjs modules.

I have a ScheduleResolverModule that imports PricingTriggersModule.

I want to publish changes from PricingTriggersModule back to SchedulerResolverModule.

I considered using an intermediary PricingTriggersResolverModule. This module **imports** SchedulerResolverModule and **is imported by** PricingTriggersModule.

A circular dependency has resulted in this case.

Is there a way i can solve this? I really want to avoid forwardRef().

Thanks!

---

**ScheduleResolverModule**

```
import { AuthModule } from '@auth/auth.module';
import { DynamicCronModule } from '@dynamicCron/dynamic-cron.module';
import { Module, forwardRef } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PricingTriggersModule } from '@pricingTriggers/pricing-triggers.module';
import { SchedulerModule } from '@schedule/schedule.module';
import { ScheduleResolverController } from '@scheduleResolver/schedule-resolver.controller';
import { ScheduleResolverService } from '@scheduleResolver/schedule-resolver.service';

@Module({
  imports: [
    SchedulerModule,
    AuthModule,
    DynamicCronModule,
    PricingTriggersModule,
  ],
  controllers: [ScheduleResolverController],
  providers: [ScheduleResolverService],
  exports: [ScheduleResolverService],
})
export class ScheduleResolverModule {}
```

**PricingTriggersModule**

```
import { EurekaDataloaderModule } from '@external/eureka-dataloader/eureka-dataloader.module';
import { PricingExperimentModule } from '@external/pricing-experiment-pcf/pricing-experiment.module';
import { PricingTriggersService } from '@pricingTriggers/pricing-triggers.service';
import { forwardRef, Logger, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { HttpModule } from '@nestjs/axios';

@Module({
  imports: [HttpModule, PricingExperimentModule, EurekaDataloaderModule],
  providers: [PricingTriggersService, Logger],
  exports: [PricingTriggersService],
})
export class PricingTriggersModule {}
```

**PricingTriggersResolverModule**

```
import { ScheduleLogModule } from '@scheduleLog/schedule-log.module';
import { forwardRef, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ScheduleResolverModule } from '@scheduleResolver/schedule-resolver.module';
import { PricingTriggersResolverService } from './pricing-triggers-resolver.service';

@Module({
  imports: [ScheduleLogModule, ScheduleResolverModule],
  providers: [PricingTriggersResolverService],
  exports: [PricingTriggersResolverService],
})
export class PricingTriggersResolverModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

your `PricingTriggersResolverModule` solution still causes the circular dependency as you noticed, the circle just has 1 more member on it.

im afraid `forwardRef(() => SchedulerResolverModule)` would be your only solution..

post more of your code (module declarations) and i can help you configure it properly

**update:**
if the only purpose of `PricingTriggersResolverModule` is to try and escape the circular then you can remove it completely, it's redundant since you still have it.
in any way you need to import the circular module with a `forwardRef(() => DependencyModule))` on both sides of the circle.
if you chose to remove the intermediate module make sure that you have the following:

```js
// ScheduleResolverModule
@Module({
  // exports, providers, controllers, etc..
  imports: [forwardRef(() => PricingTriggersModule), SchedulerModule,
    AuthModule,
    DynamicCronModule,
    PricingTriggersModule
]
})
export class ScheduleResolverModule {}

// PricingTriggersModule
@Module({
  // exports, providers, controllers, etc..
  imports: [forwardRef(() => ScheduleResolverModule), HttpModule, PricingExperimentModule, EurekaDataloaderModule]
})
export class PricingTriggersModule {}
```

if you keep it, then make sure it follow the same structure with `forwardRef(() => DependencyModule))` on both sides

Comment: Thanks for your reply Hagai. 
 
Here’s the flow of my modules. 
A -> B -> C (ScheduleResolverModule) -> D (PricingTriggersModule) -> E (PricingTriggersResolverModule).

I am thinking of how to enable E to call C after it has run a method. Would something like a callback work in this case? I know it's something to do with a middleman but i can't figure it out. I will post my code snippets shortly.

Comment: I have added the code snippets above. Thanks again for your help. I really do appreciate it! I referenced this thread as a guideline, maybe it might be useful in my case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62054703/avoiding-circular-dependencies-the-right-way-nestjs