# How to avoid circular dependency in nest js?

Tags: nestjs

I have to use the database of the A module in the B module and the database of B module in the A module is there a proper way to implement this without getting a circular dependency?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62054703/avoiding-circular-dependencies-the-right-way-nestjs

Answer (score 0):

I can assume that if you have some modules that are uses each other, it's better to introduce new module that will have common features for both modules and import this module as a dependency. Or without module. Just create a service and make custom `useFactory` for it to make nestJS know what are you doing with this service.

But more precise answer in the link.
[Avoiding circular dependencies the right way - NestJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62054703/avoiding-circular-dependencies-the-right-way-nestjs)